# Can I interrupt git pull (while it is asking for a merge)?

Tags: git, merge

Let's say I execute the `git pull` command.
It may ask me to do a merge, which as I understand is , because I had commits while the remote has gone forward.

I am right now in the editor for the `git pull` comment for the merge part of this.  Can I interrupt this editor somehow, or the whole `git pull` command?  ***If*** there is a way, ***which*** is the safest way?

(If I just close the editor without saving, of course it will simply proceed with the pull(merge))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, just execute ':q!' (force quit) in the editor and git will interpret your lack of comment as your response to NOT merge.

Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.

That last part is the secret sauce :)

Comment: I think I've inadvertently done this already: :q! in Vi. But I think git still merged, so that's why I was asking.  It's possible I've had some non-empty characters so that's why it merged .
Will try again soon!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answer that outlines quitting the text editor using `:q!`. The `:q!` will only work if you're using vi/vim as your editor.

With any other text editor, simply make sure that you remove all lines that aren't starting with a "#" character (comments). An empty commit message will not commit anything.

Run `git status` to see whether you're still in the middle of a merge. It's possible that you have to follow that up with a `git merge --abort` to stop the merge and roll back any changes. Once you have done that, you should be back to the state before the pull.